# Is multiprocessing in Python 3.4 broken?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, importerror, python-3.4

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing module in Python 3.  However, everytime I try to set up a Pool, I get the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmp.py", line 7, in <module>
    with Pool(5) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 118, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 150, in __init__
    self._setup_queues()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 243, in _setup_queues
    self._inqueue = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 110, in SimpleQueue
    from .queues import SimpleQueue
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 20, in <module>
    from queue import Empty, Full
ImportError: cannot import name 'Empty'
```

The simplest code that can easily trigger this is the first example in the multiprocessing module documentation.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

(source: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html)

My question: Is this a bug in Python 3.4?  Or am I doing something wrong?  The equivalent code works in Python 2.7.

Comment: chance of bug/error on your end >> bug in Python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a *local* module named `queue`; it interferes with the [standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

Remove it or rename it and your code will work again:

```
stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ cat test.py 
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))

stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ touch queue.py
stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ bin/python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    with Pool(5) as p:
  File "/.../python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 118, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/.../python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 150, in __init__
    self._setup_queues()
  File "/.../python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 243, in _setup_queues
    self._inqueue = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()
  File "/.../lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 110, in SimpleQueue
    from .queues import SimpleQueue
  File "/.../lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 20, in <module>
    from queue import Empty, Full
ImportError: cannot import name 'Empty'
stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ rm queue.py
stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ bin/python test.py 
[1, 4, 9]
```

If you have trouble locating it, run `python3 -c 'import queue; print(queue.__file__)'`.

Comment: You're right.  I was working in my scratch directory and, have indeed, an old queue that I wrote a long time ago.  I feel dumb now.  I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.